# builtin commands in a shell pipeline

Tags: shell, pipe

Whenn running

```
 ls | sort | cd /home
```

... I know the pipe connects the process.

In Linux, each command runs in an independent process, and we know that it passes stdout on the left to the process on the right.

But contrary to my expectations, nothing is running.
The directory change to /home should happen, but nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: `cd` reads the directory as an argument, not on `stdin` unless the directory is specified as `'-'`.

Comment: @HwanE What do you _expect_ to happen when you run `ls | sort | cd /home`? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, commands in a pipeline are executed in a different process. If you type

```
ls | sort | cd /home
```

.... this process (more exactly, one of its children: try `cd /home | pwd`) will change its working directory to `/home` and then exit. The working directory of the parent shell (the one you are working in) will not have changed.

In `zsh`, *all but the last* command in a pipeline will be executed in a different process. So in `zsh`

```
ls | sort | cd /home
```

will change your working directory, but

```
cd /home | ls | sort
```

... won't